# Accessing objects in different controllers while using different threads in cocoa

Tags: cocoa-touch, multithreading, controller, nsxmlparser

I'm pulling in xml using the cocoa NSXmlParser. Since this process most likely won't finish before my view is loaded I want to move it to a secondary thread like I have seen in many examples including the seismicxml example on the apple site.

The flow of my application is as follows.  I have a table view which cells can be clicked to get to another tableview which is populated by nsxmlparser.

I know this is how you populate an object if you are doing your logic in the app delegate:

```
[(id)[[UIApplication neare] delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addToBusStopList:) withObject:busStop waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but how do you do this if you are working in the table view controller like I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the parser finishes can't you tell the tableview to update itself:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```